# Apache 2.4 fails to start with loading php7_module: apachectl: Segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache, php-7

I installed apache 2.4.25 and php 7.1.4 from source code,everything seemed ok until I failed to start apache with a segmentation fault.

```
# /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl: line 79: 23589 Segmentation fault      $HTTPD -k $ARGV
# /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k start
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl: line 79: 23592 Segmentation fault      $HTTPD "$@"
```

the apachectl is like this from line 79:

```
case $ACMD in
start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop)
$HTTPD -k $ARGV
ERROR=$?
;;
```

When apache was installed,it was able to start.After php was installed, the httpd.conf file was added with a line:

```
LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
```

then the apache failed to start.When I removed the line,it could start again.But then php could not work.Can anybody help me please?

By the way,before installing php,I had to configure php with "--disable-fileinfo" otherwise it would stop when making install.I thought something might be wrong with memory so I checked and made swap work correctly.But nothing changed.

Comment: You need to find out where in your php library the issue is. You need to find out about the `ldd` utility and using core dumps for that. We cannot help much in that, since a `Segmentation fault` is something generic more or less, it only indicates that the process tries to access memory sections it is not allowed to. Using a core dump you can find out what _exactly_ the process tried to do when it got killed by the operating system for miss behavior. So what line of code. That should give a clear hint what has to be fixed or changed. But that is quite some effort you will have to go through...

Comment: @arkascha That's very hard for me. I tried to get to know what I should do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, that is not an easy task. Debugging a complex binary setup is a challenge. Question is: do you _really_ have to go through all this? _Why_? Why do you need a self compiled setup?

Comment: My present setup is installed through yum install, based on Apache 2.2 and php 5.3. Now some bugs have been found. I need to upgrade them. I successfully upgraded php 5 to the latest version 5.6. But I did not find a good way to yum upgrade apache to 2.4. And what's more,I think a compiled setup may be easy to patch when new bugs are reported. So I tried to compile them to latest version. If there's a easy way,that'll be good. Can you give me more advice? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no repositories available that provide versions for your system that are more up to date than what the default repositories offer?

Comment: OK,I'll try to search more repositories.Thanks again!@arkascha